# Running StringToWordVector filter in WEKA

Tags: java, filter, machine-learning, weka, arff

I am using WEKA's API on Java to develop an application. When running StringToWordVector filter (to convert the string type attributes) to my input.arff file that looks like this:

```
    @relation Instantzien_Bektorea

    @attribute 5_Ainf_Lema string
    @attribute 6_Arg_PosKat {IZE,ADJ,ADI,ADB,DET,IOR,LOT,PRT,ITJ,BST,ADL,ADT,SIG,SNB,LAB,POST}
    @attribute 7_Arg_Pos_AzpiKat {ARR,IZB,LIB,ZKI,GAL,SIN,ADK,ADP,FAK,ERKARR,ERKIND,NOLARR,NOLGAL,DZH,BAN,ORD,DZG,ORO,PERARR,PERIND,IZGMGB,IZGGAL,BIH,ELK,JOK,JNT,HUTSA}
    @attribute 8_Arg_Kasua {abl,abu,abz,ala,soz,dat,des,erg,gel,gen,ine,ins,mot,abs,par,pro,bnk,desk,aurk,bald,emen,erlt,espl,haut,helb,kaus,konpl,kont,denb,mod,mos,ondo,zhg,neg,gen_post_ine,gen_post,gen_post_abs,ala_des,soz_post_ala,zero_post_abl,-}
    @attribute 9_Argumentuaren_FSint {-,subj,obj}
    @attribute 10_Arg_Posizioa {Aurretik,Atzetik}
    @attribute 11_Dist_HKop numeric
    @attribute 12_Dist_ArgKop numeric
    @attribute 13_Framea string
    @attribute 15_Frame_Unekoa string
    @attribute Klasea {arg0,arg1,arg2,argM*LOC,argM*TMP,argM*MNR,argM*Cause,argM*ADV,argM*PRP,argM*-,argM*NEG,argM*DIS}

    @data
    eta_gero,LOT,ARR,denb,-,Aurretik,999,1,argM_PRED_arg1,ARGM_PRED_arg1,argM*TMP
    Ainf_Lema,ADI,SIN,mod,-,Aurretik,1,1,argM_arg0_arg1_PRED,argM_arg0_ARG1_PRED,arg1
    Ainf_Lema,IZE,ARR,abs,subj,Aurretik,999,2,arg0_argM_arg1_PRED,ARG0_argM_arg1_PRED,arg0
...
```

I get another a bunch of instances that wrote in output.arrf look like this:

```
@relation 'Train_Instantzien_Bektorea-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector-R1,9,10-W1000-prune-rate-1.0-N0-stemmerweka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer-M1-tokenizerweka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -delimiters \" \\r\\n\\t.,;:\\\'\\\"()?!\"'

@attribute 6_Arg_PosKat {IZE,ADJ,ADI,ADB,DET,IOR,LOT,PRT,ITJ,BST,ADL,ADT,SIG,SNB,LAB,POST}
@attribute 7_Arg_Pos_AzpiKat {ARR,IZB,LIB,ZKI,GAL,SIN,ADK,ADP,FAK,ERKARR,ERKIND,NOLARR,NOLGAL,DZH,BAN,ORD,DZG,ORO,PERARR,PERIND,IZGMGB,IZGGAL,BIH,ELK,JOK,JNT,HUTSA}
@attribute 8_Arg_Kasua {abl,abu,abz,ala,soz,dat,des,erg,gel,gen,ine,ins,mot,abs,par,pro,bnk,desk,aurk,bald,emen,erlt,espl,haut,helb,kaus,konpl,kont,denb,mod,mos,ondo,zhg,neg,gen_post_ine,gen_post,gen_post_abs,ala_des,soz_post_ala,zero_post_abl,-}
@attribute 9_Argumentuaren_FSint {-,subj,obj}
@attribute 10_Arg_Posizioa {Aurretik,Atzetik}
@attribute 11_Dist_HKop numeric
@attribute 12_Dist_ArgKop numeric
@attribute Klasea {arg0,arg1,arg2,argM*LOC,argM*TMP,argM*MNR,argM*Cause,argM*ADV,argM*PRP,argM*-,argM*NEG,argM*DIS}
@attribute ARG0_PRED_arg1 numeric
@attribute ARG0_arg1_PRED numeric
@attribute ARG0_arg1_PRED_arg1_argM numeric
@attribute ARG0_arg1_PRED_argM numeric
@attribute ARG0_arg1_PRED_argM_argM numeric
@attribute ARG0_argM_PRED numeric

...

@attribute argM_PRED_ARG1_argM_argM numeric
@attribute argM_PRED numeric
@attribute argM_PRED_arg1_ARGM numeric

...

@attribute ARGM_argM_PRED_arg1_argM numeric
@attribute arg0_ARGM_arg1_PRED numeric
@attribute arg0_ARGM_arg1_PRED_argM numeric
@attribute arg0_arg1_PRED_ARGM_argM numeric
@attribute eta_gero numeric
@attribute gaur numeric


@data
{0 LOT,2 denb,5 999,6 1,7 argM*TMP,90 1,162 1,197 1}
{0 ADI,1 SIN,2 mod,5 1,6 1,7 arg1,19 1,42 1,93 1}
{2 abs,3 subj,5 999,6 2,16 1,19 1,29 1}
```

As you will see in the output.arff file some attributes disappear from the instances (first instance-> no first attribute, no third attribute etc.) Why is this??

The Java code that runs the filter looks like this:

```
      // StringToWordVector filter
      String[] options = new String[1];
      options[0] = "-R <1,9,10>";                                    
      StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector(); 
      filter.setOptions(options);                          
      filter.setInputFormat(input.arff);                         
      Instances output_inst = Filter.useFilter(input_inst, filter);
```

Any ideas where the problem can be? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your input file is in the normal ARFF format, whereas the output file is in *sparse* ARFF, as they start with `{` and end with `}`.  (See information on the [Attribute-Relation File Format](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html))

```
{0 LOT,2 denb,5 999,6 1,7 argM*TMP,90 1,162 1,197 1}
```

In this sparse format, attributes having the value 0 will be omitted. All present attributes need to be specified by their index followed by the value. In the above example (your first instance):

- Attribute 0 => LOT
- Attribute 1 omitted => 0
- Attribute 2 => denb
- Attribute 3 omitted => 0
- ...

If you look at the definition of attribute 1, you'll see that it's not numerical but nominal, so 0 is the index of it's value, in this case `ARR`

So, there are no attributes missing, they are just omitted in the output because it is in the sparse format.

In case you're wondering why you have different attributes: That is the result of the StringToWordVector filter.